# How to solve "$" error in this line?

Tags: math-mode

This is the code where I am getting error:

```
\longrightarrow\hspace{2mm}  $\phi$ + 90 + $\beta$ + s = 180\\\\
```

Error:

You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’. Use $...$ for inline math mode, and [...] or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode. This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ).

Platform used is: Overleaf

Comment: Why didn't you write it like it should? `$\longrightarrow\hspace{2mm}  \phi + 90 + \beta + s = 180$`

Comment: Considering the ```\\\\``` at the end, is this equation meant to be placed in a line of its own? If so, you should consider using `\[ \longrightarrow\hspace{2mm}  \phi + 90 + \beta + s = 180 \]`. The `\[ .. \]` indicates what is called displayed math, see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10

Comment: don't use `$` around each symbol, the entire expression should be in a singl math expression, otherwise apart from getting errors you will not get correct math spacing for + and =, and don't use `\\ ` out of its use to end table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\longrightarrow` must be in a math environment.
Have a try:

```
\begin{math}
  \longrightarrow\hspace{2mm} \phi + 90 + \beta + s = 180
\end{math}
```

You can use any other math environment delimiter : `$..$` `\(..\)`.